# How insert unicode string into sqllite in c++?

Tags: sqlite, unicode

I used

```
 sqlite3_open16(v_st,&m_db)//SQLITE_OK
```

I want to insert unicode string.
Example:

```
sqlite3_exec(m_db,"UPDATE t1 SET a1='text'",0,0,0); //is good
```

but

```
 sqlite3_exec(m_db,"UPDATE t1 SET a1='текст'",0,0,0); //is bad
```

Answer (score 1):

When you use the `sqlite3_open16` function you open the DB with the UTF-16 encoding.
And when you use the `sqlite3_exec(m_db,"UPDATE t1 SET a1='текст'",0,0,0)` function you use the encoding of your compiler (UTF-8 by default or cp1251).

You should use the same encoding in both cases. You may do one of theese things:

1) use the `sqlite3_open` function to open it with UTF-8 encoding and enshure your compiler uses UTF-8 as well;

or

2) change your compiler encoding to UTF-16;

or

3) use the sql statement `PRAGMA encoding = "UTF-8"`

Answer (score 0):

```
    string ANSItoUTF16le(const char* v_str)
{
    string t_res;
    unsigned char* t_buf=(unsigned char*)v_str;
    auto t_size=strlen(v_str);
    unsigned char t_s='А',t_f='п',t_E='Ё',t_e='Ё',t2_s='р',t2_f='я';
    unsigned char t_c;
    for(auto i=0;i<t_size;i++)
    {
        if(t_buf[i]>=t_s&&t_buf[i]<=t_f)
        {
            t_res+='\xD0';
            t_c='\x90'+t_buf[i]-t_s;
            t_res+=t_c;
            continue;
        }
        if(t_buf[i]>=t2_s&&t_buf[i]<=t2_f)
        {
            t_res+='\xD1';
            t_c='\x80'+t_buf[i]-t2_s;
            t_res+=t_c;
            continue;
        }
        if(t_buf[i]==t_E) 
        {
            t_res+="\xD0\x01";
            continue;
        }
        if(t_buf[i]==t_e)
        {
            t_res+="\xD1\x91";
            continue;
        }
        t_res+=v_str[i];
    }
    return t_res;
}
```

and

```
sqlite3_exec(m_db,ANSItoUTF16le("UPDATE t1 SET a1='текст'").c_str(),0,0,0);
```

Comment: This is a very complex way just to use UNICODE text. You are still using char *t_buf as opposed to wchar_t *t_buf

Answer (score 0):

You can insert unicode string into sqllite in c++ by using a wrapper class on top of sqlite3.

CppSqlite3U is a unicode wrapper around the SQLite database. It allows using UNICODE types, such as wchar_t (instead of char), or It can be downloaded from [here](http://softvoile.com/development/CppSQLite3U/CppSQLite3U.zip). also described in [this article](https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/6343/CppSQLite-C-Wrapper-for-SQLite). For example: a query executed by execQuery can be of a LPCTSTR type, meaning that it can be either an array of wide chars or chars depending on whether UNICODE is defined in your project.

```
CppSQLite3Query execQuery(LPCTSTR szSQL);
```